# How to add a delay between cycles of css animation

Tags: html, css

I am rotating a circular `<div>` infinity in 360 degrees using css animation. 
After each rotation, I want a halt or delay of 5 seconds before next rotation. 
How can I achieve it?

[**Here's  a live example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qkhjm?editors=110)

Code is as following.

**CSS**

```
.circle{
    position: absolute;
    top: 4;
    right: 4;
    height: 21px;
    width: 21px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #00B5F9;
    color: white;
    font-family: varela round;
    font-size: 11;
    font-weight: 500;
    border: 1px solid white;
    -webkit-animation-name: lol;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:  ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s
}
@-webkit-keyframes lol {  
    0% { -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) }

    100% { -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg) }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="circle">56</div>
```

Comment: This QA is much cleaner than the one referenced to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
0% { -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) }
20% { -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg) }
100% { -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg) }
```

and change the duration of the rotation

```
-webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
```

So what you are doing is setting the animation to take 6's but moving the rotation to be quicker (20% is not correct for 5's wait but you can work it out). So the rotate happens and then it sits at 360deg for the remainder of the time.

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jejbq3m7/)

Comment: whoa, That's just brilliant. +1

Comment: Just out of curiosity is there any particular css property for this?  like `-webkit-animation-delay` ?

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe From what I know of there isn't. I also wanted a property for this but there isn't one yet.

Comment: `transistion-delay: 2s;` ?

Comment: @Benjamin That delays the animation the first time, that is all. So just when the animation will start.