# How to add interval between cycles of css animation which is coded in animate.css?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, animate.css

This question is [partly duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233455/how-to-add-a-delay-between-cycles-of-css-animation), but not completely. I know how to add intervals to my own animation but now the animation I'm talking about is from animate.css. I want to add intervals to its animation, say, shake. How?

Answer (score 1):

Try using javascript to achieve this.

Using -

```
    $(".ani").delay(700).each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(700*index).fadeIn(500);
    });
```

Add the `class="ani"` to your elements which require the delays and play with the timings (in milliseconds) to achieve the delays and trigger timings.

Using `animation-iteration-count: x;` you can control the number of times the animation is triggered.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
   h1 {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: shake;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-delay: 3s;
}
@keyframes shake{
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 300%; 
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations

i hope this is useful for you

animation execute continue after 3s because we define `animation-duration: 3s;`
and why animation execute continue after one time because we define `animation-iteration-count: infinite;`

Comment: But the animations are defined in animate.css and there are numerous different animations. I don't want to define the animation one by one again in my css.

Comment: you just change in animate.css file you didn't define to again.change in exiting code

Comment: I hope not to change the animate.css. More importantly, I only want to add interval between each cycle, I'll have to add a new animation whenever I want a new interval. But maybe your approach is indispensable.

Comment: using jquery you can add and remove a animation...use set interval....add and remove

Comment: eh, seemingly I should only achieve this either by copying&pasting&slightly modifying the css or by using JS.

Answer (score -1):

Just give it an id and apply css.
`#animationID { animation-duration: 2s; }`

Comment: I've used this but this only prolongs the animation duration, isn't it?

Comment: do you mean `animation-iteration-count: 5;`

Comment: No. In my exp, setting the animation-duration on an element with "rubberBand animated", for example, only makes the animation slower, and each cycle of animation actually is played consecutively, without intervals in between.

Comment: `animation-delay: 4s;` will delay from initially starting the animation but you may need jQuery for what you are try to do.

Comment: Yes. animation-delay only adds delay before the first cycle of animation but not all of them...